# How to select the difference of two layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

In the image below, there are two circles drawn in two layers. The second circle overlaps some part of the first circle. Now how can I select the only the area of first circle so that it keeps the overlapping area of second circle?

[image]

Comment: Hi krishna, welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I took the freedom to try and clarify the title of your question a little. If you disagree and think I butchered it beyond recognition, feel free to edit it back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press and hold your <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> key;
2. Hover over the thumbnail of the lower layer in the layers palette and click it—this will select all pixels in that layer;
3. Release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>;
4. Press and hold your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (to the right of your space bar);
5. Click the thumbnail of the other layer—this will remove all pixels in that layer from your current selection;
6. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: Think you changed this at some point. By default it should be Control key.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold <kbd>Control / Command</kbd> and click on the Circle 1 thumbnail in the layer panel
2. Then continue holding <kbd>control / command</kbd>, hold <kbd>alt</kbd> as well, and click on the Circle 2 thumbnail in the layer panel

Comment: Thank you, wish i could up vote.